# pandas 'match' on non-ascii characters

Tags: regex, pandas

I'm sure this is a very simple issue with regexps, but: Trying to use `str.match` in pandas to match a non-ASCII character (the times sign). I expect the first match call will match the first row of the DataFrame; the second match call will match the last row; and the third match will match the first and last rows. However, the first call does match but the second and third calls do not. Where am I going wrong?

Dataframe looks like (with x replacing the times sign, it actually prints as a ?):

```
  Column
0  2x 32
1     42
2  64 x2
```

Pandas 0.20.3, python 2.7.13, OS X.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import re

html = '<table><thead><tr><th>Column</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>2&#215; 32</td></tr><tr><td>42</td></tr><tr><td>64 &#215;2</td></tr></tbody><table>'
df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
print df
print df[df['Column'].str.match(ur'^[2-9]\u00d7', re.UNICODE, na=False)]
print df[df['Column'].str.match(ur'\u00d7[2-9]$', re.UNICODE, na=False)]
print df[df['Column'].str.match(ur'\u00d7', re.UNICODE, na=False)]
```

Output I see (again with ? replaced with x):

```
  Column
0  2x 32
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Column]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Column]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains):

```
df.Column.str.contains(r'^[2-9]\u00d7')
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Column, dtype: bool

df.Column.str.contains(r'\u00d7[2-9]$')
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: Column, dtype: bool

df.Column.str.contains(r'\u00d7')
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: Column, dtype: bool
```

Explanation: `contains()` uses `re.search()`, and `match()` uses `re.match()` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html)).  Since `re.match()` only matches from the beginning of a string ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)), only your first case, which matches at the start (with `^`) will work. Actually in that case you don't need both `match` and `^`:

```
df.Column.str.match(r'[2-9]\u00d7')
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Column, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Why not match? It returns a bool also, yes?

Comment: Yup. That'll do it! Thanks @andrew_reece.